# Read File in chunks and then read line by line using LineNumberReader. Repeat this activity

Tags: java, file, split, buffer, line-numbers

I have a file containing some 6.5 lakh lines. Now I wish to read every line of this file using LineNumberReader.

However I am encountering an outofMemoryError on adding these many number of lines to another 3rd party library..

What I intend to do is, read 200000 lines of a file at a time and add these lines to 3rd party library.

I am using LineNumberReader but I think the entire file is being read although I have provided condition that when line count reaches 200000 break the loop and add these to 3rd party library..

A code snippet for the same:

```
    LineNumberReader lnr=new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line=null;
    int i=0;      
    while(flags)
              {
     while( null != (line = lnr.readLine()) ){  
    i++;   
     3rdPartyLibrary.add(line.trim());
    if(i==200000)
                {      
                    System.out.println("Breaking");
                    lnr.mark(i);
                    break;
                }  
                if(i==400000)
                {
                    System.out.println("" );
                    lnr.mark(i);
                    break;
                }
                if(i==600000)
                {
                    System.out.println("BREAKING " );
                    lnr.mark(i);
                    break;
                }
     }
    if(line==null)
              {
                  System.out.println(" FLAG");
                  flags=false;
              }
lnr.reset();
    }
```

What I am intending to do here is read file from 0-200000 in first iteration. Then read each individual line and add to 3rd party lib.. Once this is done, read another 200000 lines from (200001-400000) and then repeat the same activity.

Need help..Can someone please guide..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I think, this error arises when the JVM fails to allocate more objects (String in your case) due to the lack of memory as your program has already occupied a lot of it. Please place a call System.gc() somewhere inside the loop and check whether it works.

Comment: I basically want a way to read 200000 lines at one go and do this process recursively till all the lines are read..I am more bothered about this rather than outoFMemory error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example that i tried a long time back, 
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/processing-huge-files-with-java.html
This solve out of memory exception.

Comment: I need something on the basis of the code sample I have provided.

Comment: oh! sorry, in ur case this wont help you. ok as u said `read 200000 lines of a file at a time and add these lines to 3rd party library.`
then what is the need of `3rdPartyLibrary.add(line.trim());` code inside the second while loop?

Comment: The while(flags) will always run till I reach the end of the file where I have checked line for null and set flags=false. The reason add is written inside the second for loop is because, as soon as I read a line I need to write it into a 3rd party library. This count should be limited to 200000 at a single time. I mean I will repeat this process of reading 200000 lines one by one and adding to lib till the end of the file is reached...!!!

Comment: Ok understood. I ran ur code , nothing false, except `try{}finally{ lnr.close(); }` so check with 3rd party library. U stored nothing anywhere, no memory leak. plz check with ur 3rd party library.

Comment: Yes..I know about the finally thing since I have not written it yet as I was more focused on the exception.. Better off I am checking with the 3rd party library itself to see if I am doing something wrong over there.